# I keep getting this error: Class referenced in the layout file, com.camerakit.CameraKitView, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android

How do I get rid of this error warning in Android Studio?

I am following this guide: https://proandroiddev.com/machine-learning-in-android-using-firebase-ml-kit-6e71a14e11f8

[build.gradle (app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrjtA.png)

```
implementation 'com.camerakit:camerakit:1.0.0-beta3.11'
implementation 'com.camerakit:jpegkit:0.1.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'
```

[activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP2O7.png)

```
<com.camerakit.CameraKitView
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_detect"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    app:camera_flash="auto"
    app:camera_facing="back"
    app:camera_focus="continuous"
    app:camera_permissions="camera">
</com.camerakit.CameraKitView>
```

Comment: use this url to download if AAR file and import in your project https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.camerakit/camerakit/1.0.0-beta3.11

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out in comments, make sure you're adding correct the repository to the library.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
}
```

Add the above code in the build.grade file (Project level) and rebuild the project.